# Adding a vector\arrow above letter in Microsoft Word 2016 without Equation Editor

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-word-2016, equation-editor

I want to get a letter with vector\arrow sign above it. How to do it without using `Equation Editor` in `Microsoft Word 2016`? Equations in `MS Word` are clumsy and inflexible structures and I want to avoid using it, since all my formulas are simple.

---

This is what I want to get:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Please try this when enter equation: `(ABC)\vec`

After entering this, you should enter some spaces.

You can find the information in this pdf: [Plain Tex Math](http://unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf) at 3.8 Stretchy Characters.

Comment: you can find the information in this pdf: 
[Plain Tex Math](http://unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf) at 3.8 Stretchy Characters

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a simpler native method than using `INSERT \ Equation`. The other option is to use `INSERT \ Object \ Microsoft Equation` which is like using a big truck to transport only a small box.

If you like to work with equations as uneditable images, use online tools like https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php.

[image]

You can copy and paste the resulted formula as an image in Word.

Comment: IMO you are correct that there is no simpler method than the current Equation Editor. For a repetitive task like this, the user can probably make that Editor almost invisible by learning *one* keyboard shortcut to toggle the editor on and off, *one* math autocorrect string and a standard way to enter the text. Then, if they want to put "whatever" with a right arrow over it, they can use <space>Alt-=(whatever)\vec<space><space>Alt-=. (Where <space> means "press the spacebar key" and "Alt-=" means "use the Alt-= shortcut". I put a <space> first to make the equation appear inline.